# 12.04 Unity capable, but still stuck with no loader/dash/

Tags: unity, nvidia, compiz

I ran

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

And it seems I pass all tests, I'm using the latest proprietary drivers, Unity 2D/Gnome works just fine, just not Unity 3D

I already tried [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) logged in using 2D, activate the plugin but still no dice.

Is there a dump I can provide to get help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've upgraded, or are using the same home partition/directory with old config files, it's possible for some old compiz configuration to break the Unity panel and launcher.  Open a terminal window and try:

unity --reset

Chris